# Python plotly обновить (перерисовать) график

Tags: python, plotly

Простой скрипт берет данные из трех файлов и строит графики.

```
import plotly.express as px  
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots  
import plotly.graph_objects as go  
import pandas as pd 

HAE = pd.read_csv('/home/gluk/tmp1/KLYT_HAE.csv')  
HAN = pd.read_csv('/home/gluk/tmp1/KLYT_HAN.csv')  
HK2 = pd.read_csv('/home/gluk/tmp1/KLYT_HK2.csv')  

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)    

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=HAE["date"], y=HAE["data"]),row=1, col=1
)  
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=HAN["date"], y=HAN["data"]),row=2, col=1
)  
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=HK2["date"], y=HK2["data"]),row=3, col=1
)

fig.show()
```

Как заставить скрипт перерисовывать графики по мере обновления файлов? Проблема в том, что все три файла обновляются одновременно, но интервалы обновления могут быть от нескольких минут до нескольких часов поэтому streaming не подходит. Спасибо.

Comment: Можете уточнить суть вопроса? Вопрос в том как отследить изменение файлов или в том как обновить график?

Comment: Вопрос в первую очередь как обновить график отображаемый в браузере. Для отслеживания обновления файлов планирую использовать watchdog, но буду благодарен за любой предложенный вариант.